# Ошибка в задаче two_sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Задача:

Вам дан список целых чисел и некоторое целевое число, которое представляет собой сумму двух чисел из этого списка.
Напишите функцию two_sum, которая принимает на вход список и число и возвращает индексы тех чисел из списка, сумма которых равна целевому числу. Подразумевается, что задача имеет ровно одно решение. Дважды использовать одно и то же число нельзя. Индексы возвращаются в виде кортежа. Для решения рекомендуется использовать словарь.

Код:

```py
def two_sum(spisok, chislo):
    b = []
    old = []
    for i in spisok:
        for j in spisok:
            if i + j == chislo and i != j and i not in old and j not in old:
                b.append(spisok.index(i))
                b.append(spisok.index(j))
        old.append(i)
    return tuple(b)
```

Ошибка:
Как я уже сказал, неизвестно где неизвестно что, где-то ответ отличается от верного согласно сайту

Comment: Пример входных данных и выходных данных?

Comment: Пример: целевая сумма *2*, список *[1, 1]*. Ожидаемый ответ: *(0, 1)*. Ваша программа вернёт пустой кортеж - ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первая задачка с [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/)

- Идем по списку и добавляем первое слогаемое `num` в словарь, где ключ текущее число из списка, а значение его индекс.
- Если находим слогаемое `res`, которое уже находится в нашем словаре, возвращаем индексы двух слогаемых.

```py
def twoSum(nums: list[int], target: int) -> tuple[int, int]:
    prev = dict()
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        res = target - num
        if res in prev:
            return i, prev[res]
        else:
            prev[num] = i

print(twoSum([2,7,11,15], 9))
```

Вывод:

```
(1,0)
```

**UPD**

- В твоем решении ошибка в условии, т.к например при `nums = [2, 2]` и `target = 4`, оно не выполнится.

```
if i + j == chislo and i != j and i not in old and j not in old:
```

- Далее, поиск индексов затратит дополнительные `O(N + N)` времени, что можно исправить использовав функцию `enumerate`

```
b.append(spisok.index(i))
b.append(spisok.index(j))
```

- Ну и вообщем данный алгоритм затритит в худшем случаи `O(N * N) + O(N + N)` - времени, что не есть хорошо, когда предложенный алгоритм выше затрит только `O(N)` - времени.

Исправленная версия:

```py
def two_sum(arr: list[int], target: int) -> tuple[int, int]:
    for i, num1 in enumerate(arr):
        for j, num2 in enumerate(arr):
            if num1 + num2 == target and i != j:
                return i, j

print(two_sum([2,2], 4))
```

Вывод:

```
(0,1)
```